# mysql_query for PHP 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I currently have a website in WordPress and the server is due to be upgraded to PHP 5.6, there are a large number of scripts which use 'mysql_' and 'mysql_query', example below:

```
$jobcount_result = mysql_query($jobcount_sql) or die ("Error ".mysql_errno() ." : ".mysql_error() ."");
```

As this extension has now been deprecated, would the alternative be to use 'mysqli' instead of 'mysql' throughout all scripts?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, although it might be a little more complicated than a simple replacement (check for errors afterwards)

Comment: Please read about $wpdb and how to use it.
You will have to replace a lot of things but at the end it will has point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this might not answer your question completely, you should rather use the `$wpdb` class, simply because it is safer and follows WordPress standards.

This will avoid a lot of headaches in the future as well :)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$jobcount_sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($jobcount_sql);
```

You can read here about the `$wpdb` Class: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb